# session_regenerate_id in an included php file when headers have already been sent

Tags: php, ajax

I have a web page where I am displaying a user's posts and in it I am including another php file which gets those posts from the database. I am doing it this way for readability purposes and also because this included php file is used for doing a ajax call. At the start I am regenerating a new session but in the file that I am including it also regenerates a new session.

posts_main.php

```
<?php

include_once '../includes/connect.php';
include_once '../includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == false) {
    header("location:../login.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="posts">
        include('list_posts.php'); ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

list_posts.php

```
<?php

include_once '../includes/connect.php';
include_once '../includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == false) {
    header("location:../login.php");
}

//connect to mysql database and echo back results

?>
```

My sec_session_start function looks like this:

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();          // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 

}
```

When I launch the main post page I get the following error:

> Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id -
>   headers already sent in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/includes/functions.php on line 24

I realise this is because I am calling session_regenerate_id after the headers have been sent but I need this in the included file for security reasons when calling the same file in the ajax call later.

Is there any way I can get around this and keeping it secure at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is output (such as text or HTML) is being sent before the session_regenerate_id() is being called.

There are various solutions to this problem already discussed on Stackoverflow if you search for "headers already sent" in PHP.  Find what output is being sent before session_regenerate_id() or just use [**output buffering**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

One easy way to determine output being sent is by replacing the session_regenerate_id() with an echo and seeing what is displayed before it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the line:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Or this way it will work in the 1st call, and not fail in the 2nd:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```

Why would you regenerate it, when session_start already created it for you?

Comment: I thought the same thing, I'm assuming he wants to generate a new session (not resume the previous), but is not going about it the right way.